# How can I have Calendar use an Alarm Clock reminderalarm for alerts?

Tags: iphone, calendar, reminders

I used Samsung Galaxy 6 for couple of years.  I loved that in the Clock you can use the Alarm and set not only time of alarm but also the date. For example, if you want to watch a game that was 4 days from now at 11AM, you could set your alarm 4 days and 3 hours from now.

It would ring your standard alarm sound until you stop it, even if it takes 7 minutes for you to stop it. So it was loud, consistent, and it would not stop sounding the alarm until you stopped it.

On iPhone I can set the alarm only 23.59 hours in advance.  I cannot set it a few days ahead because I cannot select a date, just the time.

If I use Reminders or Calendar I can set it on any day in the future but the alarm sounds that I choose will only sound once or, max, twice. I know, I tried them all.

If I am in machine shop and I can't hear first alert, I'm screwed because that reminder is gone. If I go to restroom and my calendar or reminder beeps, I am screwed again.  I missed sound and it wont beep again.

Often during the week I have different waking times, 5 on Monday and 6 on Tuesday and then 7.30 on Friday so why I cannot set Alarm on my iPhone to ring at any time on any day of the month in advance?

Is there anything that can simply perform all these functions?

- Setting an alarm on any future date
- Setting any time on that date
- Alarm continues to sound until manually stopped?

Comment: You can look into automations/shortcuts and post any development you make.